# How to fix aws-iot-device-sdk disconnect behaviour after switching internet connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I am trying to setup aws-iot-device-sdk-js with reconnect behaviour after wifi is switched and its taking around 20 mins to do so.I am not sure where i am wrong the docs doesn't have anything regarding the issue i am having as well.

I have tried going through the package docs and tried changing the keepalive time but its still showing the same output the offine is called only after 20 mins and reconnects.

```
const awsIot = require("aws-iot-device-sdk").device;
const certs = require("./certs_config");

const device = awsIot({
    keyPath: certs.KEYPATH,
    certPath: certs.CERTPATH,
    caPath: certs.CAPATH,
    deviceId: "rt.bottle.com.np",
    host: "aot2wgmcbqwsa-ats.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
    region: "ap-south-1",
    keepalive: 60
});

let delay = 4000;
let count = 0;
const minimumDelay = 250;

if ((Math.max(delay, minimumDelay)) !== delay) {
    console.log('substituting ' + minimumDelay + 'ms delay for ' + delay + 'ms...');
}
setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    device.publish('topic', JSON.stringify({
        count
    }));
}, Math.max(delay, minimumDelay)); // clip to minimum

device
    .on('connect', function () {
        console.log('connect');
    });
device
    .on('close', function () {
        console.log('close');
    });
device
    .on('reconnect', function () {
        console.log('reconnect');
    });
device
    .on('offline', function () {
        console.log('offline');
    });
device
    .on('error', function (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    });
device
    .on('message', function (topic, payload) {
        console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
    });
```

In aws console i am getting this message:

> Mqtt connection lost. Reconnect. Error code: 4. AMQJS0004E Ping timed out.

after around 1.5 mins of the network switch but in the node server setup as you can see in the code below it only receives the offline message in around 20 mins. I want to get the error/offline/disconnect as soon as its disconnects or goes offline.(i.e when receives the error on aws console) as expected.

Answer (score 0):

i am currently using the simulateNetworkFailure Function to handle the network switch issue i was having i hope it helps others having the same issue.